# UPS shipping method not showing magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods, debug, ups

I had integrated Magento UPS XML Shipping module with all live credentials. But What I see is

**No shipping Methods Available**
 I enabled the debug mode the debug file is below Error code I got is

```
<AccessRequest xml:lang="en-US">
  <AccessLicenseNumber>MYACCESSKEY</AccessLicenseNumber>
  <UserId>****</UserId>
  <Password>****</Password>
</AccessRequest>
',
  'request' => '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RatingServiceSelectionRequest xml:lang="en-US">
  <Request>
    <TransactionReference>
      <CustomerContext>Rating and Service</CustomerContext>
      <XpciVersion>1.0</XpciVersion>
    </TransactionReference>
    <RequestAction>Rate</RequestAction>
    <RequestOption>Shop</RequestOption>
  </Request>
  <PickupType>
          <Code>03</Code>
          <Description>Customer Counter</Description>
  </PickupType>

  <Shipment>      <Shipper>      <Address>
          <City> Pretoria</City>
          <PostalCode>0002</PostalCode>
          <CountryCode>ZA</CountryCode>
          <StateProvinceCode>72 Struben St, Pretoria Central, </StateProvinceCode>
      </Address>
    </Shipper>
    <ShipTo>
      <Address>
          <PostalCode>636009</PostalCode>
          <CountryCode>IN</CountryCode>
          <ResidentialAddress>01</ResidentialAddress>
          <StateProvinceCode></StateProvinceCode><ResidentialAddressIndicator>01</ResidentialAddressIndicator>      </Address>
    </ShipTo>


    <ShipFrom>
      <Address>
          <PostalCode>0002</PostalCode>
          <CountryCode>ZA</CountryCode>
          <StateProvinceCode>72 Struben St, Pretoria Central, </StateProvinceCode>
      </Address>
    </ShipFrom>

    <Package>
      <PackagingType><Code>00</Code></PackagingType>
      <PackageWeight>
         <UnitOfMeasurement><Code>LBS</Code></UnitOfMeasurement>
        <Weight>4</Weight>
      </PackageWeight>
    </Package>  </Shipment>
</RatingServiceSelectionRequest>',
  'result' => '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RatingServiceSelectionResponse>
<Response><TransactionReference><CustomerContext>Rating and Service</CustomerContext><XpciVersion>1.0</XpciVersion>
</TransactionReference>
<ResponseStatusCode>0</ResponseStatusCode>
<ResponseStatusDescription>Failure</ResponseStatusDescription>
<Error>
<ErrorSeverity>Hard</ErrorSeverity>
<ErrorCode>111057</ErrorCode>
<ErrorDescription>This measurement system is not valid for the selected country or territory.</ErrorDescription></Error>
</Response>
</RatingServiceSelectionResponse>',
) {"is_exception":false} []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the error provided by you, you can see that the measurement units used by you are `lbs`. For India, you will not get the rates with these.

You need to switch to `kgs`.

You can switch this weight unit from admin.

```
Logged in to your Magento admin panel -> go to store -> configuration -> general section -> locale options -> over there you will see weight unit option -> select which you want to set.
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my day. it's working